# How to sort GraphQL query results by custom metadata field?

Tags: content-delivery, sites-9, graphql, pca

I am looking for a way to sort GraphQL results by custom metadata field. There is a way how to filter by custom metadata field that is described in [documentation](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v1/GUID-474F27A9-98F2-4F52-8AAA-28F4E68CFFE5), however, I cannot find how to sort. Is it possible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The GraphQL result sorting currently supported the following fields only, It's possible to extend GraphQL extension in sites 9.1.

- CREATION_DATE
- INITIAL_PUBLISH_DATE
- ITEM_ID ITEM_TYPE
- LAST_PUBLISH_DATE
- NAMESPACE_ID
- OWNING_PUBLICATION_ID
- PUBLICATION_ID
- TITLE
- UPDATED_DATE

**Example:**

```
{
  items(
    filter: {
      customMeta: {scope: Item, key: "mykey", value: "42"},
      sort:{sortBy:LAST_PUBLISH_DATE, order:Descending}
    }
  ) {
    edges {
      node {
        id
        publicationId
        namespaceId
        itemId
        itemType
        title
        customMetas {
          edges {
            node {
              key
              value
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Indeed!. Refer to the SDL Documentation for [GraphQL query result sorting](https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Tridion%20Sites-v1/GUID-26FBABEA-537B-4ADF-AC55-46BF63BBDDA7) for more details.

**Update:**
This is now fixed and available HF and also needs a fix for the DXA Graphql provider level(DXA 2.2.3 is available at maven/nuget). please reach out to SDL support.

**Example query:**

```
{
    items(
    filter:{
      itemTypes:COMPONENT
      publicationIds: 5
      schema: {
        id:122
      }
    }
    sort:{
      order: Descending
      keyType: DATE
      key: "dateCreated"
      sortBy: CUSTOM_META
    }
  ){
    edges{
      node{
        customMetas {
          edges {
            node {
              key
              value
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I hope it helps.

Comment: Is there any sample code on how to extend GraphQL extension in sites 9.1?

Comment: Good question, @Stan. It's probably worth starting a new TRex question so others can find it along with the eventual answer. :-)